# Update action is not working in Razor Pages with Modal Pop Up for Add/Edit actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a razor pages with modal pop up for adding and editing records,My Add operation is working as expected but my record is not updating on editing the record.
Functioning of the screen will be like this
1)Listing Page
[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGLWY.png

2)Modal Popup for Adding New Asset

[image]

3)Modal Popup for Editing Asset

[image]

This is my StaffAssets.cshtml file

```
@page
@model Contractor_HRMS.Pages.Staff.Directory.StaffAssetsModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<br />

<!-- CREATE NEW ASSET BUTTON-->
<div class="text-center">
    <button class="btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalStaffAssets">
        Add New Asset
    </button>
</div>
<br />

<!-- CREATE NEW ASSET MODAL-->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalStaffAssets" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header text-center">
                <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Add New Asset</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <form asp-page-handler="AddAssetsDetails" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-complete="staffAddAssetsCompleted">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input asp-for="StaffAssets.StaffID" type="hidden" value='@Request.Query["StaffID"]' />
                    <input asp-for="StaffAssets.EmpID" type="hidden" value='@Request.Query["EmpID"]' />
                    <!-- Asset Name -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="StaffAssets.StaffAssetName" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                        <select asp-for="StaffAssets.StaffAssetName" name="StaffAssets.StaffAssetName" asp-items="Model.ShowAssetName" class="form-control-staff">
                            <option value="">Please Select</option>
                        </select>
                        <br />
                        <span asp-validation-for="StaffAssets.StaffAssetName" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Issued Quantity -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="StaffAssets.IssuedQty" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                        <input asp-for="StaffAssets.IssuedQty" name="StaffAssets.IssuedQty" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                        <span asp-validation-for="StaffAssets.IssuedQty" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Issued Date-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="StaffAssets.IssuedDate" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                        <input asp-for="StaffAssets.IssuedDate" name="StaffAssets.IssuedDate" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                        <span asp-validation-for="StaffAssets.IssuedDate" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Return Qty-->
                    <div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
                        <label asp-for="StaffAssets.ReturnQty" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                        <input asp-for="StaffAssets.ReturnQty" class="form-control-staff" value="NULL" /><br />
                        <span asp-validation-for="StaffAssets.ReturnQty" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- STAFF ASSETS LIST-->
@if (Model.ShowStaffAssets != null)
{
    <table class="table" border="1" style="width:750px;margin-left:175px;" >
        <thead style="background-color:#DC3545">
            <tr>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShowStaffAssets[0].StaffAssetName)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShowStaffAssets[0].IssuedQty)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShowStaffAssets[0].IssuedDate)</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.ShowStaffAssets)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StaffAssetName)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IssuedQty)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IssuedDate)</td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="~/images/pencil(1).png" alt="Edit">&nbsp;<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_@item.StaffAssetName">Edit</a> |
                        <img src="~/images/icons8-delete-trash-16.png" alt="Delete">&nbsp;<a asp-page="./Delete">Delete</a>

                        <!--EDIT STAFF ASSET-->
                        <div id="myModal_@item.StaffAssetName" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <!-- Modal content-->
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header text-center">
                                        <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Edit Asset</h4>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <form asp-page-handler="EditAssetsDetails" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-complete="staffEditAssetsCompleted">
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <input asp-for="StaffAssets.StaffID" type="hidden" value='@Request.Query["StaffID"]' />
                                            <input asp-for="StaffAssets.EmpID" type="hidden" value='@Request.Query["EmpID"]' />

                                            <!-- Asset Name -->
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label asp-for="StaffAssets.StaffAssetName" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                                                @*<input asp-for="StaffAssets.StaffAssetName" value="@item.StaffAssetName" class="form-control-staff" />*@
                                                <select asp-for="@item.StaffAssetName" name="StaffAssets.StaffAssetName" asp-items="Model.ShowAssetName" class="form-control-staff">
                                                    <option value="">Please Select</option>
                                                </select>
                                                <br />
                                                <span asp-validation-for="StaffAssets.StaffAssetName" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                                            </div>

                                            <!-- Issued Quantity -->
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label asp-for="StaffAssets.IssuedQty" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                                                <input asp-for="@item.IssuedQty" name="StaffAssets.IssuedQty" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                                                <span asp-validation-for="StaffAssets.IssuedQty" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                                            </div>

                                            <!-- Issued Date-->
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label asp-for="StaffAssets.IssuedDate" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                                                <input asp-for="@item.IssuedDate" name="StaffAssets.IssuedDate" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                                                <span asp-validation-for="StaffAssets.IssuedDate" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                                            </div>

                                            <!-- Return Qty-->
                                            <div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
                                                <label asp-for="StaffAssets.ReturnQty" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                                                <input asp-for="StaffAssets.ReturnQty" class="form-control-staff" value="NULL" /><br />
                                                <span asp-validation-for="StaffAssets.ReturnQty" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

This is my StaffAssets.cshtml.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Contractor_HRMS.Data;
using Contractor_HRMS.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Contractor_HRMS.Pages.Staff.Directory
{
    public class StaffAssetsModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public StaffAssetsModel(ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext)
        {            
            _context = applicationDbContext;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public StaffAssets StaffAssets { get; set; }

        public StaffAssets StaffIDExists { get; set; }

        //-----------Asset Name -------------------------//        
        public SelectList ShowAssetName { get; set; }

        public IList<StaffAssets> ShowStaffAssets { get; set; }
        public async Task OnGetAsync(int? StaffID)
        {
            ShowAssetName = new SelectList(_context.Assets, "assetname", "assetname");
            //StaffAssets = await _context.StaffAssets.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.StaffID == StaffID);
            ShowStaffAssets = _context.StaffAssets.Where(c => c.StaffID == StaffID).OrderBy(c => c.StaffAssetName).AsNoTracking().ToList();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAddAssetsDetailsAsync(StaffAssets StaffAssets)
        {
            ShowAssetName = new SelectList(_context.Assets, "assetname", "assetname");
            
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }
            else
            {
                _context.Entry(StaffAssets).State = EntityState.Added;
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                ShowStaffAssets = _context.StaffAssets.Where(c => c.StaffID == StaffAssets.StaffID).OrderBy(c => c.StaffAssetName).AsNoTracking().ToList();
                return new OkResult();
            }
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostEditAssetsDetailsAsync(StaffAssets StaffAssets)
        {
            ShowAssetName = new SelectList(_context.Assets, "assetname", "assetname");
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }
            else
            {
                var staffassets = await _context.StaffAssets.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.StaffID == StaffAssets.StaffID && c.EmpID == StaffAssets.EmpID && c.StaffAssetName == StaffAssets.StaffAssetName);
                await TryUpdateModelAsync<StaffAssets>
                    (staffassets,
                    "StaffAssets",
                    s => s.StaffAssetName,
                    s => s.IssuedQty,
                    s => s.IssuedDate);
               // _context.Entry(StaffAssets).State = EntityState.Modified;
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                ShowStaffAssets = _context.StaffAssets.Where(c => c.StaffID == StaffAssets.StaffID).OrderBy(c => c.StaffAssetName).AsNoTracking().ToList();
                return new OkResult();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

*** Edited ******
I have changed my edit functionality to

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostEditAssetsDetailsAsync(StaffAssets StaffAssets)
        {
            ShowAssetName = new SelectList(_context.Assets, "assetname", "assetname");
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }
            else
            {
                var staffassets = await _context.StaffAssets.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.StaffID == StaffAssets.StaffID && c.EmpID == StaffAssets.EmpID && c.StaffAssetName == StaffAssets.StaffAssetName);
                staffassets.StaffAssetName = StaffAssets.StaffAssetName;
                staffassets.IssuedQty = StaffAssets.IssuedQty;
                staffassets.IssuedDate = StaffAssets.IssuedDate;
                
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                ShowStaffAssets = _context.StaffAssets.Where(c => c.StaffID == StaffAssets.StaffID).OrderBy(c => c.StaffAssetName).AsNoTracking().ToList();
                return new OkResult();
            }

        }
```

Its fetching the correct record from database and assigning the proper value,but the update query 'await _context.SaveChangesAsync();' is showing like this

UPDATE [StaffAssets] SET [IssuedDate] = @p0
WHERE [StaffID] = @p1;

*****EDITED**************
My StaffAssets Model Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Contractor_HRMS.Models
{
    public class StaffAssets
    {
        //--- Staff Id ---//
        [Key]
        public int StaffID { get; set; }

        //--- Emp Id ---//  
        
        [Display(Name = "Employee ID*"), StringLength(100)]
        public string EmpID { get; set; }

        //--- Asset Name ---//
        
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Asset")]
        [Display(Name = "Asset Name *"), StringLength(100)]
        public string StaffAssetName { get; set; }

        //--Issued Quantity ---//
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Issued Quantity")]
        [Display(Name = "Issued Quantity*"), StringLength(10)]
        public string IssuedQty { get; set; }

        //--Issued Date ---//
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Issued Date")]
        [Display(Name = "Issued Date*")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime IssuedDate { get; set; }

        //--Return Quantity ---//
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Return Quantity")]
        [Display(Name = "Return Quantity*"), StringLength(10)]
        public string ReturnQty { get; set; }

        //--Return Date ---//
        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Return Date")]
        [Display(Name = "Return Date*")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? ReturnDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last Modified By")]
        public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last Modified TimeStamp")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? LastModifiedTimestamp { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGLWY.png):

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bzuV.png):

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5mbT.png):

Comment: check errors from the ModelState  property on your controller

Comment: Hi @Tapiwa Tachiona, Modelstate validations are proper . This code snippet is not working properly await TryUpdateModelAsync<StaffAssets>
                    (staffassets,
                    "StaffAssets",
                    s => s.StaffAssetName,
                    s => s.IssuedQty,
                    s => s.IssuedDate);

Answer (score 0):

AsNoTracking() instructs EF not to track your changes

Comment: if im removing AsNoTracking(),getting this error 'Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException'

Answer (score 0):

Try to update it like this:

```
var staffassets = await _context.StaffAssets.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.StaffID == StaffAssets.StaffID && c.EmpID == StaffAssets.EmpID && c.StaffAssetName == StaffAssets.StaffAssetName);

_context.Entry(StaffAssets).State = EntityState.Modified;
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: i have already tried this,same error.Its because the query will be like this, UPDATE [StaffAssets] SET [IssuedDate] = @p0 WHERE [StaffID] = @p1; what i need is my where clause will be like this WHERE StaffID = 'value' AND EmpID = 'Value' AND StaffAssetsName = 'Value' . It should be something like this.

Comment: No ,its not updated yet.Is there a way to execute the query directly without using LINQ?

Comment: `its not updated yet` not updated in view or in database? I have tested on my side, and it updated correctly in the database.

Comment: its not updated in both,My database table structure is like this CREATE TABLE StaffAssets
( 
 StaffID INT NOT NULL,
 EmpID VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 StaffAssetName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 IssuedQty VARCHAR(10),
 IssuedDate DATETIME,
 ReturnQty VARCHAR(10),
 ReturnDate DATETIME,
 LastModifiedBy  VARCHAR(255),
 LastModifiedTimestamp  DATETIME 
)
ALTER TABLE StaffAssets ADD PRIMARY KEY (StaffID,EmpID,StaffAssetName);

Answer (score 0):

May be it can help you

```
        // Update entity in DbSet
        _context.StaffAssets.Update(entity);

        // Save changes in database
        _context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: UPDATE [StaffAssets] SET [EmpID] = p0, [IssuedDate] = p1, [IssuedQty] = p2, [LastModifiedBy] = p3, [LastModifiedTimestamp] = p4, [ReturnDate] = p5, [ReturnQty] = p6, [StaffAssetName] = p7
WHERE [StaffID] = p8; this is how the update query looks like,i want to pass other two column name in the where condition.

Comment: context.Tasks
    .Where(t => t.StatusId == 1)
    .Update(t => new Task { StatusId = 2 }); like this?

Comment: i want a linq query for this sql - UPDATE [StaffAssets] SET [EmpID] = p0, [IssuedDate] = p1, [IssuedQty] = p2, [LastModifiedBy] = p3, [LastModifiedTimestamp] = p4, [ReturnDate] = p5, [ReturnQty] = p6, [StaffAssetName] = p7 WHERE [StaffID] = p8 AND [EmpID] = p9 AND [StaffAssetsName] = p10